# alert() method is not working with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, alert

When I run my server socketio, all my html page works, except for the element alert(). I have no idea where is this problem comming from :/
PS: This line works fine:

```
document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = places;
```

Thank you very much :)
Nathan

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = message;
})
 socket.on('depart', function(places){
    alert('hi');
    document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = places;
 })
```

Comment: nodejs doesn't have an alert function ... nor does it have document.getElementById for that matter - however, this code is in the browser, right?

Comment: Yes he is. (this code does not come from the file executed by nodejs, it's my index.html)

Comment: So why the nodejs on the title and tag?

Comment: Because I think this error is related to nodejs